# What can I do with my server side error in kendo scheduler?

Tags: laravel, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I want to show a popup error whenever there is a conflict on the server side on my web app, it is either when updating or creating an event in my kendo scheduler.

In my code if ever the create and update is successful I basically return response the json of the updated/created event , now my question is if ever the event is in conflict with the other what shall i return to my view that can be read by kendo scheduler that will trigger an alert/popup window that shows that there is a conflict ?

I have tried using `return Redirect::route('error')` , `return Redirect::action(Controller@action)` , `return view('error')` but it only returns an html page in my preview instead of redirecting to that page .

Is there anyways that I can achieve what I want ?

Comment: It depends on how exactly your dataSource in configured. You can try this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/error . If your transport uses functions, see this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.update

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is already solved. What I did was to put a logic inside my complete:{} jquery function . 
so here is the sample code of what I did .

```
complete: function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
                            if (textStatus == 'success') {
                                this.read;
                            } 
                            else {                               
                                window.location = 'conflict';
                            }
                        }
```

while in my controller i threw a status code if ever there is an error on my server side .

```
return response()->json('your json')->setStatusCode(500,"ERROR");
```